# SelectListItem not Returning Results - MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have tried a multitude of different posts and tags and mixtures and not getting a return of data on my select lists.  I have even ready that some people have to use jquery to highlight the lists before sending them;  This is incredibly doable IF selecting the item actually passed the item!   I am willing to use Jquery, I am willing to update the model, I am willing to do whatever it takes to get the model data BACK, but it seems all of those return count=0 or null.

I am using 2 list boxes with some movement inside of them and want to return the contents of both listboxes upon completion.

(If there is another way to be doing this, please share!)

Model:

```
    public class RoleAddRemoveListBoxViewModel
{

    public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>  CurrentRoles { get; set; }
    public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>  NonMemberRoles { get; set; }



}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ManageUserRoles(string userList)
    {

        List<SelectListItem> lbMemberRoles = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<SelectListItem> lbNonMemberRoles = new List<SelectListItem>();


        var user = (from u in db.Users
                                where u.UserName == userList
                    select u).SingleOrDefault();

        // prepopulate roles for the view dropdown
        var roleList = db.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr =>
        new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();



        var userRoles = UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id);

        foreach (var role in roleList)
        {
            if (userRoles.Contains(role.Value.ToString()))
            {
                lbMemberRoles.Add(role);
            }
            else
            {
                lbNonMemberRoles.Add(role);   
            }
        }
        RoleAddRemoveListBoxViewModel lbvm = new RoleAddRemoveListBoxViewModel
        {
            CurrentRoles = lbMemberRoles,
            NonMemberRoles = lbNonMemberRoles
        };

        return View(lbvm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateUserRoles(RoleAddRemoveListBoxViewModel model)
    {

        TempData["updateState"] = "User Role Updated Successfully!";


        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

View:

```
@model WebDocEditor.Models.RoleAddRemoveListBoxViewModel
@{
using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateUserRoles", "Roles", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <form>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentRoles)
                    <div>
                       @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.CurrentRoles, Model.CurrentRoles)

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group-vertical col-xs-1">
                    <div id="moveRightbtn" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></div>
                    <div id="moveLeftbtn" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NonMemberRoles)
                <div>
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.NonMemberRoles, Model.NonMemberRoles)
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    </body>


}
```

}

After action edit:  I Wanted to throw in the JQuery I used for the highlighting since I see so many threads on how THEY got it to work and wanted to show what worked with my combination/setup:
JS on View:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#moveRightbtn').on('click', function () {
        var selectedCurrent = $('#CurrentRoles option:selected');
        $('#NonMemberRoles').append($(selectedCurrent).clone());
        $(selectedCurrent).remove()
        //alert(selectedCurrent);

    })

    $('#moveLeftbtn').on('click', function () {
        var selectedNonMember = $('#NonMemberRoles option:selected');
        $('#CurrentRoles').append($(selectedNonMember).clone());
        $(selectedNonMember).remove()
        //alert(selectedNonMember);

    })

    $("#submitBtn").on('click', function (e) {

        $("#CurrentRoles option").prop('selected', 'selected');
        $("#NonMemberRoles option").prop('selected', 'selected');
    });

           });
</script>
}
```

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select multiple="multiple">` to a collection of complex objects (in your case `List<SelectListItem>`). You need a property to bind to - e.g. - `string[] SelectedRoles` and use it as `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedRoles, Model.CurrentRoles)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lists needs to be separate from what you're returning.. you should set your model up like this.

```
public class RoleAddRemoveListBoxViewModel
{
    public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>  CurrentRolesList { get; set; }
    public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>  NonMemberRolesList { get; set; }
    public string[] CurrentRoles {get;set;}
    public string[] NonMemberRoles {get;set;}
}
```

List boxes will return an array of whatever is selected.. In this case you can just set the properties to `string[]`

In your view, use the new properties as the expression and the List properties as the selectList

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentRoles)
            <div>
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.CurrentRoles, Model.CurrentRolesList)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical col-xs-1">
            <div id="moveRightbtn" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></div>
            <div id="moveLeftbtn" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NonMemberRoles)
            <div>
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.NonMemberRoles, Model.NonMemberRolesList)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

in your controller.. make sure you set the right properties to your lists

```
public ActionResult ManageUserRoles(string userList)
{

    List<SelectListItem> lbMemberRoles = new List<SelectListItem>();
    List<SelectListItem> lbNonMemberRoles = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var user = (from u in db.Users
                where u.UserName == userList
                select u).SingleOrDefault();

    // prepopulate roles for the view dropdown
    var roleList = db.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr =>
    new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
    var userRoles = UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
    foreach (var role in roleList)
    {
        if (userRoles.Contains(role.Value.ToString()))
        {
            lbMemberRoles.Add(role);
        }
        else
        {
            lbNonMemberRoles.Add(role);
        }
    }
    RoleAddRemoveListBoxViewModel lbvm = new RoleAddRemoveListBoxViewModel
    {
        CurrentRolesList = lbMemberRoles,
        NonMemberRolesList = lbNonMemberRoles
    };

    return View(lbvm);
}
```

not sure why you had this actionresult as a [HttpPost] but you might want to remove that attribute..

the way list boxes work, it will only post back what is actually selected.. so you might have to select all of the items in each list if you want to return all of the values in them

Comment: Thank you, I am implementing this shortly and will let you know.  As far as the HTTPPOST:

I am very new to web design, mvc, all of it.  I am having a lot of trouble of knowing when to use the post tag and when not to, since I have such a myriad of different ways of posting data depending on the page.  Partial views use ajax calls which require the POST, it seems.  

Again, due to newbie-ism and not understanding the full implication of the tag, it has been part of my troubleshooting process to remove or add the tag and see the different post results I get.

Comment: Yep, adding the that actually go INTO the list was what was missing.  In hindsight, that makes sense.  I knew I was close :(  Marked as answered, thank you for the great updated example of my code & the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Add `string[]` for your return properties.

```
public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>  CurrentRoles { get; set; }
public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>  NonMemberRoles { get; set; }
public string[] SelectedCurrentRoles{ get; set; }
public string[] SelectedNonMemberRoles{ get; set; }
```

and use `MultiSelectList` in your `ListBoxFor`. I would use a different model to pass in but you could use your existing `List<SelectListItem>`

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedCurrentRoles, new MultiSelectList(Model.CurrentRoles, "Value", "Text"))
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedNonMemberRoles, new MultiSelectList(Model.NonMemberRoles , "Value", "Text"))
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, as it looked like it worked as well as the other answer, though I'd rather have the list built in the controller and then presented so I went with the other method.